# Yealink phone cannot obtain IP address

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I had a T43U phone bridging to a desktop connected to my network behind an unmanaged switch. The issue began when both of them lost connectivity. After disconnecting both I plugged the computer to the LAN cable and it connected to the network fine. I then placed a small desktop switch to avoid using the bridge as I had the same issue happen before. The phone cannot obtain IP address now, even if I connect it directly to the switch. any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SU. Unfortunately phones are off-topic here.